# How to create a custom home page for slug "home" or cms_home (custom theme)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

I am creating a new custom theme for magento2.4.5. and to create a custom home page for base url (domain.com), I have done following:

In app/design/frontend/my-vendor/my-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml (home.phtml contains the homepage html):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cms_page" display="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                  name="homepage" template="Magento_Theme::html/home.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This code only works for main/url "www.domain.com". But when I open "www.domain.com/home url", it still shows the magento2 default home page content instead of my custom home page content. I can not use admin panel because this config needs to be saved with my custom theme.

What is the difference between "cms_index_index" and "cms_home" and how to load custom homepage for "cms_home" handle ([www.domain.com/hom](http://www.domain.com/hom)) as well? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one configuration where you can select your default pages in magento.

Go to **Admin** -> **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Geneal** -> **Web**

Scroll down and you'll find **Default Pages** tab, and check if your default home page is selected

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks. I need to save this config with custom theme. how to change default home page through xml config?